# Having problems submitting an iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, itunes, app-store-connect

im getting these errors:

> The Bundle ID Hasselknippe-Solutions.iTangera defined in your Xcode
>   Project does not match the Bundle ID that you entered for this app in
>   iTunes Connect com.Hasselknippe-Design.iTangera.

and

> Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid,
>   or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.

How to i fix these errors?

Thanks

Comment: You should have two certificates in Xcode, one for development, and the other for distribution.  Sign and archive with the distribution certificate. I make this annoying mistake all the time.

Comment: The 1st problem:  Your app's bundle id should be com.Hasselknippe-Design.iTangera as you had entered in iTunes Connect when you created the new app.

Comment: Whoever voted to close this as "off topic" is incorrect.  Code signing an iPhone app is a common development concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to solve this problem (assuming your Apple Provisioning Portal is correctly behaving)

1) Go to organizer

2) Provisioning profile and delete everything.

3) Check "Automatic Device Provisioning" and hit refresh (You will get all your profile back).

4) Go to "Build setting" and use new Provisioning profile.

5) Go to your identifier in summary and check does it match to app ID in Apple developer portal or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be extremely meticulous in getting all your provisioning profiles to match. I'd start over with my provisioning profiles, making sure you have a distribution one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure all 3 of the below match, and should NOT have the 10 digit Apple ID prefix

1. Bundle ID in Xcode (Targets -> Info -> Bundle Identifier)
2. App ID in Provisioning Portal
3. Bundle ID in iTunes Connect for your app (i messed up here, make sure you create this only after everything is configured in Provisioning Portal)